# Marking indirect usages of classes, methods etc

Tags: java, annotations, ide

> Is there a standard way in Java to mark classes, methods etc. that are used by other parts of the program in indirect ways (think: reflection) which are not discoverable by the usual search-functions of IDEs?

In one particular example I have a bunch of classes with a couple of hundred small validation methods. Validation occurs basically by listing all methods of those classes via reflection and executing one by one them on the given object. (It's more complicated than that, but that's the underlying idea)
Now my IDE understandably marks each and everyone of those methods as "unused" because there are never directly called, only via reflection.

A similar problem occurs in another part of the program where several dozen helper classes reside, some of which are almost certainly unused and could be deleted. But: In some rare cases the fields of these classes are accessed via reflection and the usual search functions of the IDE cannot find these usages (again: very understandably so).

I know that it is impossible for the IDE to solve this problem without outside help. Hence my question whether there are already established ways like annotations for example to clearly mark these cases. Of course I could define such an annotation myself, but I'd rather go with an accepted standard if one exists.
Is there even an IDE that can recognise them and warn me automatically if I'm doing stuff like that?

Comment: Well, in the Eclipse version I use, *any* annotation on an unused member lets the warning go away, well, except those obviously not having the “will be processed automatically” semantic, i.e. except `@Deprecated`. Which is very convenient, as it is not unusual to have already project specific annotations controlling the automated processing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is not a *standard* way to mark indirect control flow (reflection, Android intents, callbacks, etc.).

There are some tools that provide their own ways to analyze indirect control flow.

For example, the [Checker Framework](https://checkerframework.org/)'s [reflection resolution](https://checkerframework.org/manual/#reflection-resolution) uses the [`@MethodVal`](https://checkerframework.org/api/org/checkerframework/common/reflection/qual/MethodVal.html) annotation to indicate the possible targets of a reflective invocation.  It also has ways to indicate [Android intents](https://checkerframework.org/manual/#sparta-checker).

Answer (score 1):

You typically annotate those classes with `@SuppressWarnings("unused")` to get rid of IDE warnings

Comment: Getting rid of the warnings isn't the main focus of my question. I'm more interested in how to express the semantic relationship "X uses Y" between classes/methods/...